# Best way to split large vmware vmdk disk to 2 smaller disks

Tags: vmware, esxi, vmdk

I have a large disk of 8 TB on a VMware VM (filled with around 7 TB of data). I need to transfer the data / split the disk into 2 smaller disks of 5tb (as an example). Can someone suggest the best way to achieve this?

I am new to VMware and its tools, I have tried searching online, but I have not really found anything. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "split the disk into 2 smaller disks"?  Do you mean that you want the guest OS to see two disk devices, or do you mean that you want to split a single `.vmdk` file into multiple files that are still presented to the guest OS as a single disk device?

Comment: @jamesdlin splitting the disk into 2 and presenting to the os as a single logical disk would be the best expectation. Is that possible? If not, i will have to be content with 2 disks.

Comment: If you just want the virtual disk to exist as multiple `.vmdk` files instead of as a single one, then power off the VM and run `vmware-vdiskmanager` on the `.vmdk` file. I'm not sure about for ESXi, but with VMware Workstation you'd run `vmware-vdiskmanager -r source.vmdk -t 1 destination.vmdk`.

Comment: Could you please explain the -r and -t flags and what they do

Comment: Run `vmware-vdiskmanager` with no arguments to see command-line help.  It should explain that `-r` specifies a source disk to convert and that `-t` specifies the disk type to convert to.

Answer (score 0):

Simple but time consuming:

1. Create an extra *.vmdk, partition and format it inside yor VM.
2. Transfer (move) some files to the new space, using the VM.
3. Exit VM.
4. Use VMWare's "clean disk" feature on the initital disk to regain the space that was occupied by the moved files.
5. Repeat from 2, until done

... assuming that you do not have temporary space for (all) the data to be moved to the second disk.

*From memory, no VMWare to check in*